# How to be a paragraph formatted strongly with a div

Tags: html, css

i have a website (http://www.theqlick.com/festivalfreaks.php) and on some browsers the p tag doesn't seem to work.

It seems to shoot upwards instead of staying in the right place. I want to know how to create a div with strict padding on it.

My CSS/HTML code is below:

```
         .pinboard2 {position:absolute; margin-top:150px; left:300px; width:200px; height:25px;}

                 .intro1 {   position:relative;
                 font-family: Noteworthy, Comic MS Sans;
                 font-size:16pt;
                 margin-top:-860px;
                 left:-290px;
                 width:520px;
                 text-align:center;
                color:white;}




                <DIV class="pinboard2">
<p id="intro1" class="intro1">Want to become a Chat! Member? Click <a href="home.php"> Here </a> to Login/Register. </p>
   <p class="intro"><br><b>We, at Qlick</b>, have decided that nothing is more important than the benefit of music. Music is a massive part of our lives. Music makes us who we are and people can tell your personality with music. <br><br>

<b>With us working on a way of expressing music </b> in a fantastic way, we have developed and built a way in which people can feel at home regarding festivals.<br><br>

   <b>Festivals are events and parades for music</b>, where people can come together and enjoy it. FestivalFreaks declares itself the Place for Festivals, in which more and more festivals are being added and supported for the platform of FestivalFreaks.
```

Comment: can you please specify which element in particular is causing the issue and give an example of a browser type / version which has the problem?

Comment: As jamie said, if can give more details, would be much easier. anyway , try to add float:left to the p tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what's happening when I open it in old IE but the way you are doing this is very bad.
something like this is will be ok

```
<style>.pinboard2 {background: url("yourbg.png") no-repeat;}</style>
```